# Populate MySQL table according to Checkbox click in Android through PHP script

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am working on an Android App which sends data from the app to an online MYSQL Database through PHP Script.The app is used to record the input values of a user.I also have a checkBox which is used to check if the user was absent and does not have any record to fill.There is a column in the database table called "ABSENT" which will either be marked as "NO" when the user clicks on Submit after entering the data.And the "ABSENT" column will be marked as "YES" if the checkbox is clicked and the values for the iput field will be filled with 0. So,what I am trying to do is that if the user enters the values and clicks on Submit Button, I call a AsyncTask and pass the values of each input field alongwith a String value for the "ABSENT" column.

```
String type = "insertDetails";
 String absent = "No";
 BackgroundAsyncTask asyncTask = new BackgroundAsyncTask(InsertDataActivity.this);
asyncTask.execute(type,enquiryValue,retailValue,collectionValue,
                     bookingValue,evaluationValue,testDriveValue,homeVisitValue,
                            username,dateValue,absent);
```

The CheckBox code is:

```
boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
if (checked) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are marked as absent for the Day.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
String type = "insertDetails";
String absent = "Yes";
BackgroundAsyncTask asyncTask = new BackgroundAsyncTask(InsertDataActivity.this);
asyncTask.execute(type,enquiryValue,retailValue,collectionValue, bookingValue,evaluationValue,testDriveValue,homeVisitValue,
                            username,dateValue,absent);
```

The AsyncTask code is:

```
if (type.equals("insertDetails")){
            try {
                String enquiry = params[1];
                String retail = params[2];
                String collection = params[3];
                String booking = params[4];
                String evaluation = params[5];
                String test_drive = params[6];
                String home_visit = params[7];
                String user_name = params[8];
                String dateTime = params[9];
                String absent = params[10];

                URL url = new URL(insertData_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("enquiry", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(enquiry,"UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("retail","UTF-8") + "="+ URLEncoder.encode(retail,"UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("collection", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(collection,"UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("booking", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(booking,"UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("evaluation", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(evaluation,"UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("test_drive", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(test_drive,"UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("home_visit", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(home_visit,"UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("date", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(dateTime,"UTF-8")
                        +URLEncoder.encode("absent","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(absent,"UTF-8");
```

And the PHP Script for sending data to MYSQL is:

```
    $enquiry = $_POST["enquiry"];
    $retail = $_POST["retail"];
    $collection = $_POST["collection"];
    $booking = $_POST["booking"];
    $evaluation = $_POST["evaluation"];
    $test_drive = $_POST["test_drive"];
    $home_visit = $_POST["home_visit"];
    $user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
    $update_date = $_POST["date"];
    $absent = $_POST["absent"];

    $mysql_qry1 = "INSERT INTO employee_details(enquiry,retail, 
    collection,booking, evaluation, test_drive, home_visit, name, date,time,absent) values ('$enquiry','$retail','$collection','$booking','$evaluation','$test_drive',
    '$home_visit','$user_name','$update_date','$time','$absent');";
$conn->query($mysql_qry1);
```

But this is not producing the desired result.The "ABSENT" column is null when I try to insert data. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Dude, there is a lot of code repetition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `+ "&"` in post_data initialization code in the end of the first line here:

```
+ URLEncoder.encode("date", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(dateTime,"UTF-8")
+ URLEncoder.encode("absent","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(absent,"UTF-8");
```

In result you'll get strange date and no absent parameter. Just add `&`.

Comment: OMG,that was the silly mistake I made.Thanks a lot.You saved my day. Thanks once again :)